# Ferramenta para debugar uma stored procedure no linux

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

gostaria de saber se alguém conhece ou até mesmo já usou alguma ferramenta para realizar um *debug* em *stored procedures* em *linux*.

Atualmente estou utilizando o *MySQL Workbench* e o *DBvisualizer*, mas até onde eu sei nenhuma delas fornece a funcionalidade de *debugar* uma *procedure* internamente.

Comment: Não entendo o por que usar os termos em inglês neste caso. Uma duvida, você quer *debugar* exatamente o que? Desempenho?

Comment: Não entendo exatamente qual o a relevância de usar ou não usar os termos em inglês. Gostaria de "debugar" o "corpo" do "procedimento"

Comment: Claro desculpe esqueci que todo mundo fala inglês :) (desculpe o sarcasmo). Entendi você quer "debugar" a estrutura da query e talvez o resultado também (eu acho).

Comment: @JoãoManolo Dê uma olhada nesse [projeto](https://github.com/CaptTofu/Stored-procedure-debugging-routines), deve ser de seu interesse. Esse [artigo](http://www.bluegecko.net/mysql/debugging-stored-procedures/) deve ser útil também.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento convenhamos que na nossa área de atuação o minimo de conhecimento em inglês é fator fundamental para qualquer desenvolvedor. Isso mesmo! Apenas a estrutura da query, pois ela é bem extensa e cansativa.

Comment: @QMechanic73, não conhecia esse projeto vou dar uma olhada!

Comment: @JoãoManolo eu sei disso, mas na minha opinião você deu "enfase" o que faz o uso delas ficar estranho. Eu pessoalmente tenho conhecimento de Inglês (apenas em leitura) só que ao meu ver o termo *feature* no contexto da pergunta nada teve haver com **"programação"**, caberia ali talvez algo como *funcionalidade* ou *ferramenta*.

Comment: Ok @GuilhermeNascimento, levando em consideração que você tenha mais experiência aqui na comunidade vou editar a pergunta. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Obrigado pela consideração pela minha dica :) Boa sorte e seja bem vindo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, acabei por adotar a seguinte abordagem:

instalei o *crossover* (que implementa o *wine* como base) no *ubuntu 14.04* e logo depois o [mydebugger](http://mydebugger.com/) (sugerido pelo Anthony Accioly) e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Sei que não é bem o que você está procurando, mas você sempre pode fazer um:

```
SELECT CONCAT('O valor de x é', x);
```

No meio do seu stored procedure. Isso "imprime" o valor de uma variável na tela.

Se realmente precisar de um debugger, encontrei algumas ferramentas como o [MyDebugger](http://mydebugger.com/).

Comment: Então Anthony Accioly eu adotei essa prática, mas está sendo um pouco trabalhosa e massiva. Infelizmente o MyDebugger não "roda" corretamente com o wine (já fiz o teste pela manhã).